# accidentally deleted the function for Resize Images extension

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I accidentally deleted the function for Resize Images extension and now im in a limbo state. I no longer want this extension and I cant uninstall it because the function was deleted.
[image]

How do I go about removing this extension from firebase?

Comment: Did you attempt uninstalling the Extension from the Firebase Extensions dashboard [as described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/manage-installed-extensions#uninstall). Usually, all extensions could be uninstalled from the Firebase Extensions dashboard.

Comment: Hi, Yes I followed that guideline to uninstall the extension. The way I understand it, is that the extension uses the same cloud functions that installed it to uninstall itself. I did not know that initially, so in order to remove all traces I deleted the function first before uninstalling it through the dashboard.

Comment: @AmirH you can contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support). They might be able to uninstall it for you.

Comment: Thanks @RosárioPereiraFernandes I'll do that!